# PostgreSQL Selecting last updated of category type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `cars`, which has fields `make` `model` and `update_at`.

`updated_at` is a DateTime

```
make    | model     | updated_at
----------------------------------
Ford    | Fiesta    | 12-Jan-2010
Chevy   | Sliverado | 13-Jan-2010
Ford    | Focus     | 13-Jan-2010
```

I want to find the last updated car of each make like:

```
make    | model     | updated_at
---------------------------------
Chevy   | Sliverado | 13-Jan-2010
Ford    | Focus     | 13-Jan-2010
```

Normally I would just `group by` but in postgresql if I group by `make` I have to include any other selected columns in the `group by` or in an aggregate function.

How do I get my desired result.

Comment: GROUPing wouldn't get you what you want anyway.  OMG Ponies answer looks correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PostgreSQL 8.4+:

```
WITH sample AS (
   SELECT t.make,
          t.model,
          t.updated_at,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.make
                                ORDER BY t.updated_at DESC) AS rank
     FROM CARS t)
SELECT s.make,
       s.model,
       s.updated_at
  FROM sample s
 WHERE s.rank = 1
```

### PostgreSQL prior to 8.4:

This uses a self join, but the problem is you'll get duplicates if a make has two or more models with the same maximum updated_at value:

```
SELECT x.make,
       x.model,
       x.updated_at
  FROM CARS x
  JOIN (SELECT t.make,
               MAX(t.updated_at) AS max_date
          FROM CARS t
      GROUP BY t.make) y ON y.make = x.make
                        AND y.max_date = x.updated_at
```